# Linux device driver for a gps module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, uart

I am fairly new to linux, I am currently trying to integrate a gps module to a linux ARM controller. The gps is ublox NEO M8N and I have it connected to UART6. I need help to start communicating to the gps. I have searched for some documents but I couldn't find any relevant ones. I understand that I first need to write a kernel device driver for it, however I have no idea where to start. Could somebody point me to the right direction or tell me how I can write the device driver and start reading the latitude and longitude from gps.

Comment: no need for a kernel device driver for that.  There are already uart drivers for linux and the NMEA data from the gps is trivial to parse.  kernel drivers are a gross overkill, and overhead.

Comment: Thanks! Probably should learn to write kernel drivers soon for more complicated uses

Comment: there is certainly value in writing a driver and getting experience, and good books on the subject that walk you through it.  this protocol doesnt NEED a driver, the uart or usb uart you are using to connect to it, sure/yes, but to decode, no thats the difference in NEED between a file system driver to load a document off of the file and the word processor software used to process that document, more like a text editor as this protocol is simple.  or like a driver to talk to the disk and software that reads a jpeg or bmp or tiff.  the transport wants a driver, the payload in this case doesnt..

Comment: NEED a driver.  ..

Comment: http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/  once you get this plugged in, use a dumb terminal program, minicom, teraterm, putty etc to look at the serial data (9600N81 or 4800 or 2400) then look at this link for reference.

Comment: the info described in the link is stale in some places and not in others.  but the overall how they start, how they end with a checksum framework and the common ones will become obvious using a reference like this.   xxRMC for example...

Answer (score 6):

The ublox GNSS receiver support seems to be available from 4.19 Linux kernel release. You can see the driver [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/gnss/ubx.c) and it's device tree compatible ID's points to the support of ublox Neo M8 [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/gnss/ubx.c#n135).

Also have a look at the device tree binding documentation [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gnss/u-blox.txt).

If you need help understanding device trees, see Thomas Petazzoni's presentation [here](https://bootlin.com/pub/conferences/2013/elce/petazzoni-device-tree-dummies/petazzoni-device-tree-dummies.pdf). I am assuming you know how to know compile and deploy custom kernel images for your device.

Comment: But, from what I understand, it still doesn't parse the NMEA messages? It's not like it exposes some values through sysfs?

Comment: Does this driver also work for *"Ublox MAX-7Q GPS module"*?